# Not able to send email - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am unable to send email via following configuration.

```
$config = array();
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$config['charset']='utf-8';
$config['crlf']="\r\n";
$config['newline']="\r\n";
$config['priority']=3;
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
$config['smtp_port']=587;
$config['smtp_crypto']="tls";
$config['smtp_user'] = '************';  
$config['smtp_pass'] = '************'; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 120;
$this->email->initialize($config);    
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

I have checked millions of blog and articles. 
Same configuration is working properly on production but not on staging environment.

Following error is generated:

Message: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Handshake timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check to enable Open SSL module in `php.ini`?

If not then check the points below.

- Open your `php.ini` file
- Search this line: `;extension=php_openssl.dll`
- Enable the module by removing `;` char.
- Save the file and restart **Apache**.

Then do check. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
```

change to

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://office365.com';
```

Comment: Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://office365.com:587